# How to integrate loops with arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm prompting the user to enter a number between 50 and 100.

(Default value for the prompt is 100.)

The input, minus one, is then displayed on the screen followed by spaces.

Fore example, if user enters 60, this is what I want to be displayed:

```
01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08
...
53 54 55 56
57 58 59
```

So far I'v done the following, but I can't figure out the problem or what to do next:

```
num = Number(prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100"));
var arr= new Array(parseInt(arrayLength));  
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = arr[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just parseInt on the return value from the "prompt", and then you can create an array that is mappable. Once that is done, you can just join the entire array with a space, which will give you `1 2 3 ... etc.`

If you are looking for the most basic format where there are no line-breaks, this is a simple version:

```js
var num = parseInt(prompt('Please enter a number between 50 and 100')) || 100;
var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(num - 1))
  .map(function(x, i) {
    return i + 1;
  });
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Otherwise, if you are looking for the more complex formatting and with the line breaks, here is the same concept modified a little bit:

```js
var num = parseInt(prompt('Please enter a number between 50 and 100')) || 100;
var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(num - 1))
  .map(function(x, i) {
    var actual = i + 1;
    if (actual < 10) {
      actual = '0' + actual;
    }
    if (i % 4 === 3) {
      actual += '<br>';
    }
    return actual;
  });
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a string with the numbers and then set the `innerHtml` of your div to that string:

```
num = Number(prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100"));
var result = "";
for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    result += i + " ";
}
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = result;
```

If you want the numbers `1-9` to be displayed like `01 02 03...` you can do so with this version:

```
num = Number(prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100"));
var result = "";
for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    if(i < 10){
  result += "0" + i + " ";
  }else{
        result += i + " ";
  }
}
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = result;
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv1Ldfat/) as reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I don't know why you need the array?

Just loop from start to end and add spaces after each number (while padding it) and add line breaks after every 4<sup>th</sup> number.

```js
var num = Number(prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100")) || 100;

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = generateText(num, 4);

function generateText(n, cols) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    result += pad(i, 2, '0') + ' ';
    if (i % cols === 0) {
      result += '<br />';
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function pad(val, n, ch) {
  val = '' + val;
  while (val.length < n) {
    val = ch + val;
  }
  return val;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Since we are going for brevity here. /s

Here is some "code golf" to scratch your itch :)

```js
var num = Number(prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100")) || 100;
num = num < 50 ? 50 : (num > 100 ? 100 : num);
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = Array
  .apply(null, Array(num - 1))
  .map(function(x, i) { return (i < 9 ? '0' : '') + (i + 1); })
  .reduce(function(s, x, i) { return s + x + (i % 4 === 3 ? '<br />' : ' '); }, '');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```